# CMake retrieve output path

Tags: build, cmake, output

In my Application the user can click on a "Build" button. This will invoke a file dialogue where the user selects the folder with the CmakeCache. After that I'll invoke the `cmake --build` command with `system(command)` and the executeable will be built.

Now I'd like to know the path where the executeable was built. I need to copy files into that path.

I know that the file located at `/CMakeCacheFolder/projectname/projectname.dir/Release/projectname.log` contains the compiler log with the output path in the last line. But is there some other way?

Comment: I've never used it, so I can't write an answer, but you might want to look into CMake's [file API](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-file-api.7.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the file API is very overwhelming as a CMake beginner ( as most of CMake tbh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output directory of the executable/library target `tgt` can be obtained with [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#target-dependent-queries)

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:tgt>
```

Because this is a *generator expression*, it can be used only in limited cases. (CMake documents every command and parameter, for which a generator expression can be used).

---

If you know, that output directory for the target is set via assigning `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable, then you may read either this variable or the target's property [RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html). Unlike to the generator expressions, the variable's and the property's values can be used everywhere.

But note, that in case of multi-configuration generators (like Visual Studio), configuration name is appended to the variable's (or property's) value for obtain real output directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer but too much for a comment:

You can define the output directories for executables, shared objects, and libraries for a project as follows:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
```

And as you determine where to build you now have a common output directory under a well known path.
The directories could also be given on a configuration basis (`Debug/Release/RelWithDebInfo/...`) as follows

```
CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG
CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE
CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELWITHDEBINFO
```

Hope that helps you further.

Comment: Yes, I'm using it this way already. If I had a proper project launcher for creating new projects with my App all paths would be set by me. But right now I need to determine them at runtime...